# Fluid Flow PDE with Mass Conservation

Tags: differential-equations

Modeling a simple stepped nozzle for gas flow and having difficulties with the application of the mass conservation equation as part of the boundary conditions.

I am following the fluid flow example from http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html

Easy enough... however

Setting up the PDE is easy enough but the boundary conditions have me stumped. The example makes arbitrate conditions on the pressure which is exactly the quantity I want to solve for.

Region

```
\[CapitalOmega]=RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0,0},{.25,1}],Rectangle[{.25,.25},{.5,.75}]];
RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega],AspectRatio->Automatic,MaxRecursion->1]
```

Kernel

```
op = {Inactive[
   Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
     u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative], MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y], 
Inactive[
   Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
     v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative], MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y], \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}], Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y]} /. \[Mu] -> 1;
```

Equation

```
pde = op == {0, 0, 0};
```

Boundary Conditions

Input (x=0) uniform input velocity and pressure

```
bsc1 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 0.], DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 1, x == 0.]
```

Sidewalls, obviously no velocity

```
bsc2 = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, 0 < x < 0.5]
```

Output, the part I have issues with since the mass conservation equation is related to the boundary conditions is something like

```
Integrate[u[0.5,y]*p[0.5,y],{y,.025,.75}] == Integrate[u[0,y]*p[0,y],{y,.025,.75}]

bcs3 = DirichletCondition[?????, x == 0.5]};
```

bcs = {bcs1,bsc2,bcs3}

NDSolve

```
{xVel, yVel, pressure} =  NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, 
p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
 "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}}];
```

Plot

```
ContourPlot[xVel[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 10]
```